Markov chains, random walks and uniform measures
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with a finite number of vertices and edges.
Consider $x,y \in V$ (possibly $x=y$).
I am interested in walks on $G$ that start at $x$ and end at $y$. For each $N \geq 1$, I consider the space $V^N$ endowed with the uniform measure on these walks of length $N$.
My question is whether it is possible to encapsulate all this information in the space $V^{\mathbb{N}}$.
Specifically, is there a way to construct a measure on $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ or a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with state space $V$ such that, for each $N$, I can somehow recover the uniform measure on walks of length $N$ (perhaps via conditional probabilities) by either considering the first $N$ coordinates in $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ or examining the first $N$ steps of the Markov chain.
I attempted to construct a measure in $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ by taking the limit of measures $\mu_N$ supported on the desired walks, but it is unclear if such a limit exists.

What do you mean? If for each $N$, $(X_1, \dots, X_N)$ has uniform distribution on walks starting at $x$ and ending at $y$, then in particular $X_N=y$ for all $N$.

@JamesMartin I have edited my question, perhaps it is clearer now.

If your asking about the conditions under which existence holds, then maybe the Daniell Kolmogorov Theorem helps.

If you have a single graph and you identify nodes x and y of interest, it may not be possible to have, for all n, a  n-hop path that starts at x and ends at y. Also, if node y does not have an edge from itself to itself,  taking a 3-hop path from x to y prevents you from taking a 4-hop path from x to y.

For simplicity assume that $G$ is not bipartite (which is equivalent to saying that for all $x,y\in V$ and all sufficiently large $n$, there is a walk of length $n$ from $x$ to $y$).
Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph $G$ (i.e. for $x,y\in V$, $A_{x,y}=1$ if $\{x,y\}\in E$ and $A_{x,y}=0$ otherwise).
From Perron-Frobenius theory, one gets that $A$ has a largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ (at most the maximum vertex degree of the graph) and that there is a strictly positive vector $h=h_x, x\in V$ which is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. for all $x\in V$,
$$
\sum_{y:\{x,y\}\in E} h_y
=
(Ah)_x
=
\lambda h_x.
$$
Writing $W_x(n)$ for the number of walks of length $n$ starting from $x$, one has the following interpretation: for some constant $c$, for all $x$:
$$
W_x(n) \sim c h_x \lambda^n \text{ as }n\to\infty. 
$$
Now you can define a stochastic matrix $P$ by
$$
P_{x,y}=\lambda^{-1}h_y/h_x.
$$
Then you can get the limit property you refer to in your last paragraph. Fix some $k$, and consider the uniform distribution over walks of length $n$ starting from $x$. As $n\to\infty$, the distribution of the first $k$ steps of such a walk converges to the distribution of the first $k$ steps of the Markov chain with matrix $P$ started at $x$.
You also get the sort of conditioning property you were asking about. If you take the Markov chain with matrix $P$, started from $x$, and condition it to be at site $y$ at time $k$, then the conditional distribution of the first $k$ steps is uniform over all walks from $x$ to $y$ of length $k$. You can see this because a given walk $(x, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{k-1}, y)$ has probability
$$
\begin{align*}
P_{x, v_1}P_{v_1, v_2}\dots P_{v_{k-1}, y}
&=
\lambda^{-1} h_{v_1}/h_x \,\, \lambda^{-1} h_{v_2}/h_{v_1}\,
\dots\,
\lambda^{-1} h_y/h_{v_{k-1}}
\\
&=\lambda^{-k} h_y/h_x
\end{align*}
$$
which is the same for all such walks.
More generally, by similar reasoning, if you condition on the chain being at site $x$ at time $m$ and at site $y$ at time $m+k$, then the conditional distribution of the path of the chain between those times is uniform over length-$k$ walks from $x$ to $y$.

Thank you for your answer!
